# Show how Mathematica defines a function

Tags: special-functions, implementation-details

Is there a way to show how Mathematica defines a function, such as

```
In: Something[Sqrt], Out: Sqrt[x] -> x^(1/2)
```

As far as I understand it the command [Definition[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html) should do the job, but unfortunately it does not work on built in functions. I am asking because more complicated functions than Sqrt, such as for example the [JacobiAmplitude[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiAmplitude.html), are not well documented in the Help section, and give different results with different programs.

Since I got a solution containing those functions which are not defined uniformly everywhere, I would need to know how to interpret the output generally so I could do the calculation with pencil and on paper if I had to .

I tried to reconstruct the definitions myself with the informations given at [NIST](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16), and I got this far:

[image: own definitions]

That gives the same results like the built in functions for some ranges, but not for others; also it takes literally hours to compute the definitions I defined myself, even when I let the sum run to a small finite value instead of infinity.

The built in [JacobiAmplitude[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiAmplitude.html) in contrast evaluates in a few seconds and for all given input values, so I assume I'm doing something wrong with my own definitions.

Comment: 1. Using the integral definition directly for the complete elliptic integral is not the most efficient way for numerical evaluation; `EllipticK[]` is built-in, or if you must, `ArithmeticGeometricMean[]`. `EllipticNomeQ[]` is also built-in, and the most efficient algorithm also depends on the AGM. 2. The series for the Jacobian amplitude you are displaying has very limited numerical utility. 3. Note that *Mathematica* uses the parameter $m$ instead of the modulus $k$ as the second argument for the elliptic integrals and elliptic functions.

Comment: 4. Since a good amount of `JacobiAmplitude[]` is implemented as top-level code, `PrintDefinitions[]` from the ``GeneralUtilities` `` package can be revealing.

Comment: Have you looked at `MathematicalFunctionData` introduced in v10.3 (with `ToEntity` as demonstrated on its documentation)? I believe this is very much what you're looking for, and trying to extract this information from the way Mathematica actually *works* is probably a relatively futile effort in comparison.

Comment: MathematicalFunctionData["JacobiAmplitude", "SeriesRepresentations"]  works fine, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't necessarily how these functions are *implemented*, but `MathematicalFunctionData` gives a way to access definitions that are *equivalent* to the ones Mathematica uses.

```
(* There are a total of 348 functions to choose from *)
Length[functions = MathematicalFunctionData[]]
```

> ```
> 348
> ```

```
functions[[1]]["Definition"]
```

> ```
> {Function[{\[FormalX]}, 
>    Inactivate[
>     ConditionalExpression[
>      Abs[\[FormalX]] == \[FormalX], \[FormalX] \[Element] Reals && \[FormalX] >= 0]]], 
>    Function[{\[FormalX]}, 
>    Inactivate[
>     ConditionalExpression[
>      Abs[\[FormalX]] == -\[FormalX], \[FormalX] \[Element] Reals && \[FormalX] < 0]]], 
>    Function[{\[FormalZ]}, 
>    Inactivate[
>    Abs[\[FormalZ]] == Sqrt[Re[\[FormalZ]]^2 + Im[\[FormalZ]]^2]]]}
> ```

We can process the output to make it more readable:

```
MakeBoxes[formattedConditionalExpression[expr_, cond_], form_] := 
  MakeBoxes[Row[{expr, Text@Style["  for  ", GrayLevel[0.5]], cond}], form]

prettyDefinition[f_Entity] := 
  Column[
    Activate[HoldForm /@ fromFunction[f["Definition"]]] /. 
      ConditionalExpression -> formattedConditionalExpression,
    Spacings -> 1
] // TraditionalForm

SetAttributes[fromFunction, Listable];
fromFunction[HoldPattern[Function][vars_List, body_]] := standarize[body]

standarize = With[{hash = Dispatch[Thread[Rule[ToExpression /@ CharacterRange["\[FormalA]", "\[FormalZ]"], ToExpression /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]]]]},
  # /. hash&
]

prettyDefinition[Entity["MathematicalFunction", "BesselY"]]
```

[image]

There are other representations you can access too (like integral, sum, etc) through `EntityValue`. There are 50 different properties for mathematical functions:

```
Length[EntityProperties[Entity["MathematicalFunction", "BesselY"]]]
```

> ```
> 50
> ```